# Generated PDF from HTML, with itext (5.5.6), ignores font-size definition from CSS

Tags: java, itext

I'm using itext 5.5.6 to generate PDF files from HTML documents built trough thymeleaf.

The html is displayed correctly in browsers.
However, when generating the PDF, it displays all the styles correctly, except the definition of "font-size".

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        ...

        // itextpdf e itext tools

        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, cvos);

        document.open();

        // CSS
        CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
        CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(cssFis);
        cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

        // HTML
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        // XML Worker
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        p.parse(bais);

        document.close();

    }
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
.tabela {
    width: 90%;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.cabecalho {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.linha_numero {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Cadastros Veiculo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tabela" class="tabela">
        <tr class="cabecalho">
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">ID</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">PLACA</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">PROPRIETARIO</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">CPF</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">RENAVAM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="linha_numero" rowspan="1" colspan="1">0</td>
            <td class="linha_numero" rowspan="1" colspan="1">X</td>
            <td rowspan="1" colspan="1">X</td>
            <td class="linha_numero" rowspan="1" colspan="1">0</td>
            <td class="linha_numero" rowspan="1" colspan="1">0</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please attach the complete HTML and CSS

Comment: I have the same problem - did you find a solution?